# I can't add mailto-links with Editor

Tags: devdemon, editor

We're using Editor (3.2.3) but we can't add a mailto-link. When using the link-button you get 3 options: URL, Site page and Email. When selecting e-mail we see a dropdown with the label 'link item' but the dropdown is empty. When creating a link this way it creates a empty href.

Any idea how to do this?

Comment: A screenshot of the editor modal window you're seeing might help too.

Answer (score 1):

Contact our DevDemon support. I believe this has been fixed with a bugfix.

Answer (score 0):

I went over to Redactor to try the editor out but the standard 'link' button behaves differently to how you describe. When I click the link icon it drops down with "Insert Link" and "Unlink".

Incidentally, if I select "Insert Link" I get 2 text boxes for "URL" and "Text" and a checkbo for "Open link in new tab", if I enter URL:`mailto:me@my.com` Text:`me@my.com` I get a mailto link exactly as I wanted!

Perhaps you could try adding a "URL" link, and for the URL entering the full mailto syntax, does that give you a decent link??

Also, can I ask what Redactor plug ins are loaded in with Editor? I don't have a licence to download Editor from DevDemon so I can't see for myself! Perhaps its loading the [PredefinedLinks](http://imperavi.com/redactor/plugins/predefined-links/) or another custom plugin to allow for EE integration (Site page for router pages, ect)?

Comment: I thought of entering the mailto-syntax in the linkfield too, but the settings add http:// for every link. I don't want to turn that off, since our client is not that technical (they forget the http: otherwise).

Comment: Of course, makes sense :) Perhaps you can have a dig around the module and identify the plugin thats giving you this alternative format of "Link" button?